# Calculating with xor variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I do my calculations like this:

```
117^196
```

I get:

```
177
```

Now what I want to do is to get 117 back so I need to make a replace

```
(replace)^196 = 117
```

Whats the opposite operation from the xor operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of xor is xor :).  If you xor something twice `(a^b)^b == a`.

This is relatively easy to show.  For each bit:

```
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
0 ^ 0 = 0
```

Doing this on any pair of numbers `a`,`b`, it's easy to see that

`a^b` xor'd by either `a` or `b` yields the other (xor `a` yields `b`, and vice versa)

```
1 2 filter result
0^0^0      = 0
0^1^0      = 1
0^1^1      = 0
1^0^0      = 1
1^0^1      = 0
1^1^1      = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just `xor` it self.

like `+`'s opposite is `-`

`xor`'s opposite is `xor`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the result that you got: 177

```
117 ^ 196        = 177         | () ^ 196
117 ^ 196 ^ 196  = 177 ^ 196   | self-inverse
117 ^ 0          = 177 ^ 196   | neutral element
117              = 177 ^ 196
```

XOR has three important properties. It is

- associative
- commutative
- self-inverse

This means that a value is its own inverse:

```
a^a = 0
```

Since it is also both commutative and associative, you can rearrange and xor-expression containing an event amount of the same operands like this:

```
a^O^b^c^O^d = O^O^a^b^c^d = 0^a^b^c^d = a^b^c^d
```

You could say that operands that appear an even amount of time "cancel each other out".